# Can we use CPU instead of GPU to train custome YOLO model for object detection

Tags: opencv, python-3.6, object-detection, yolo

I want to train YOLO model for my custom objects data-set. I read about it everywhere on various sites and everybody is talking about GPU should be used to train and run YOLO custom model.
But, due to I don't have GPU I am confused about what to do? Because I can not buy a GPU for that. Also, I read about Google Colab but I can not use it, that I want to use my model on offline system.
I am scared after seeing the system utilization of the YOLO used in the program from github:
https://github.com/AhmadYahya97/Fully-Automated-red-light-Violation-Detection.git.
I was running this on my laptop having configuration:
    RAM: 4 GB
    Processor: Intel i3, 2.40 GHz
    OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: sure you can train on cpu. If you want to train an 80 class yolov3 you'll need about 64GB RAM and a lot of time.

Comment: Ohhh... But I want to train only  vehicles class, Vehicle Types (Two Wheeler, Four Wheeler, Three Wheeler, Etc.), and I have only 10 days to present my work. So what can I do for it. I want to run all this only on CPU and 4 GB RAM.

Comment: training on cpu could work in 10 days and maybe less than 4GB is enough for 1 class. But without any experience 10 days might not be enough to achieve good results. Good luck.

Comment: Thank You... Can I train YOLOv3 on google colab and use it on CPU? It might be possible to use it on real time with good speed.

Comment: I dont have any experience with google colab

Comment: I am learning about OpenCV DNN. If I got better results then I will post here.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is going to be lot slower, yes you can use CPU only when training and make prediction. If you are using original Darknet Framework, set the GPU flag in Makefile when installing darknet to `GPU=0`.

How to install darknet : https://pjreddie.com/darknet/install/

Then you can start to train or predict following this guide : https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/